# javascript variable value lost when outside object

Tags: javascript

This may sound a newbie question but I'm having really hard time with variable scopes in Javascript.

I have the following JS snippet:

```
<script>
window.IDFVPlugin.getIdentifier(function(result){ uuid = result; });
alert(uuid);
</script>
```

I want to use the variable `uuid` anywhere in the script outside the `window` object. `uuid` returns the correct value only when inside the object and the value is lost when outside. So the alert above will log an undefined variable error.

Comment: Did you try declaring it before the window statement?

Comment: If `IDFVPlugin .getIdentifier` is async at all, then an alert of `undefined` would make sense. Any chance you could share the code for `getIdentifier` ?

Comment: tried that but it still undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use a callback function. Result should be used inside of callback body. If you try to use it immediately after main function call - it will not be yet available

```
window.IDFVPlugin.getIdentifier(function(result){
 uuid = result;
 alert(uuid); 
});
```

Comment: That's right. I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/goq91eg1/) to show an asynch callback. If it would be a synchronous callback the approach with adding the result to the window obj. or to a previous defined variable would work. For testing synch just uncomment `callback(data);`